# gdi, get width of asian characters

Tags: gdi, cjk

```
        int dx[8];
        int fit;
        SIZE the_size;

        res = GetTextExtentExPointW(dc, L"WWWWWWWW", 8, -1, &fit, &dx[0], &the_size);
```

This works, `dx` is filled with numbers 7 14 21 etc. But when I try to do the same for asian characters, like `L"薔薇薔薇薔薇薔薇"`, this function fails. I even created a font for this, it doesn't change anything.

```
        HFONT hFont = CreateFont(14,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            FW_DONTCARE,
            FALSE, //fdwItalic
            FALSE, //fdwUnderline
            FALSE, //fdwStrikeOut
            SHIFTJIS_CHARSET,
            OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
            NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY, 
            VARIABLE_PITCH,
            TEXT("MS PGothic"));

        if (hFont == NULL) FUCK();

        SelectObject(dc, hFont);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forth parameter should be the maximum width allowed, not `-1`. Use a large value instead. Check to make sure `GetTextExtentExPointW` succeeded.

```
if(GetTextExtentExPointW(dc, L"薔薇薔薇薔薇薔薇", 8, 1000, &fit, &dx[0], &the_size))
{
    ...
}
```

Note that a Unicode code point may require 4 bytes, or 2 `wchar_t` for each code point.